# port-reachability issues; socket proxies

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, support, vidalia, socks

I tried hooking Tor up to a socket proxy. But it won't let me use it. It says "Tor is unable to work in this browser." What do I do about this? It originally worked. Any thoughts? Is this a problem with Vidalia?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you add some more details (which socket proxy, what exactly did you do, etc.)?